# Based on a REGEX pattern set a value using Groovy in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

Based on a REGEX validation I am trying to set a value which is not happening as expected in Groovy Jenkins pipeline
If version = 1.1.1 or 1.5.9 or 9.9.9 like that then it has to be a managed store else like 1.22.9 or 1.99.9 ... tmp store. Below is what I tried with

```
String artefact_bucket_name
def artefact_version = "1.99.0"
if (artefact_version ==~ /[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}/) {
 artefact_bucket_name = "managed-artefact-store"
}
if (artefact_version ==~ /[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1}/) {
 artefact_bucket_name = "tmp-artefact-store"
}
echo "Application version to deploy is ${artefact_version} from Artefact store ${artefact_bucket_name}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a mistake in the second regex, that is overriding first one. e.g. when you have `artefact_version = 1.1.1` - It matches first regex and second regex as well, so it always will be `tmp-artefact-store`.

I would change the second regex to match string like:

`/[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1}/` - Notice I changed `{1,2}` to only `{2}`. This will exclusively match strings like "\d.\d\d.\d", so version like `1.1.1` will match only first regex and version like `1.99.9` - only second

Comment: Thank you. I missed noticing that override. Due to have {1,2} it was overriding. Chaging it to {2} resolved the issue.

Comment: Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for that The fourth bird, tried omitting it and got the same result. Cheers